Factoring bivariate quadratic polynomials.
I want to know if there is any simple method for factoring quadratic polynomials with two variables. Can anyone recommend me a good book from where I can learn about this topic?

Can you give any examples of the type of polynomial you're interested in? If they're homogeneous, it's trivial (the same as factoring a quadratic in one variable). If not, you probably want to look up degenerate conic sections: an equation of the form $F(x,y)=0$ where $F$ is a quadratic in $x$ and $y$ describes a conic.

The question is factorize -3x^2 -2xy +8y^2 +11x -8y -6 . In my book firstly the parts with the x and the constant term are factorized. Then only the y and the constant term are factorized. In both cases two sets of factors are found both having the constant term. Then these two factors are combined for the result. I want to what sort of method is this? Is there any book that covers this method and will this method work for three variables polynomials? And also is there any alternative method to this method?

The simplest approach is to make an ansatz substitution and compare coefficients. In your example, you could use $-3(x+ay+b)(x+cy+d)$, and also impose WLOG that $a\le c$. Comparing coefficients for $xy$ and $y^2$ gives you $a$ and $c$, and you can go from there.

Could you please give me some textbooks from which I can learn this?
